# Is there any situation when the value of location.href and document.URL will be different?

Tags: javascript, html

when we write (document.URL === location.href) so true because they points to the same object but according to book, javascript: the definitive guide (page 302) they can be different if server redirect has occured.

> URL : A string specifying the url from which document wad loaded. The
>   value of this property is same as the location.href property of window
>   object expect when server redirect has occurred.

i wrote some php redirects scripts and tested but they are always same. It will be helpful for me to get the example of such situation. thanks, sorry for weak engilsh.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no such condition when document.URL and location.href will be different. The only difference between both is that document.URL is a read-only property of document(i.e. one can only retrieve the value of current URL from it) where as we can get or set URL using location.href.